# Why can I not access the first argument in \NewDocumentEnvironment?

Tags: environments

I want to write the second argument (the first real argument aside from the body) after the quote on the right hand side.

Somehow it is not seen as an argument. Why? How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{textquote}{O{}+b}
    {\begin{samepage}\begin{addmargin}{2.5cm}\guillemotright#2\guillemotleft\end{addmargin}\end{samepage}}
    {\raggedleft \textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{textquote}{René Descartes}
        I think therefore I am.
    \end{textquote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're declaring the argument to be optional…

Comment: O is an optional argument, so you should use `[René Descartes]`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. I did not know that you also needed to declare optional arguments in `[]` with \NewDocumentEnvironment`. I guess since the definition does use `{}`instead I was mislead...

Comment: xparse allows you to define various argument types, which one you need (m, O, o, b ...) depends on your needs, read the documentation.

Comment: The argument is required, so it should be `m`, not `O{}` (and then you use braces at call time).